# Tried to transfer a Javascript based webpage on an Android app (using both WebView and Context + doit)... doesn't work anyhow

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm developing an android app, and I was doing good, when I had the need to use some JS functions, that had been successfully developed in a web page months ago (so it's a HTML page with JS functions within it), but there's no way to make them work in android.

I tried with Context, this way:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    doit(
            "MY JAVASCRIPT HERE"
           +"AND HERE"
           +"AND HERE"
           +"AND SO ON";
         );
}

void doit(String code)
{
    // Create an execution environment.
    Context cx = Context.enter();

    // Turn compilation off.
    cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

    try 
    {
        // Initialize a variable scope with bindnings for  
        // standard objects (Object, Function, etc.)
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

        // Set a global variable that holds the activity instance.
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(
            scope, "TheActivity", Context.javaToJS(this, scope));

        // Evaluate the script.
        cx.evaluateString(scope, code, "doit:", 1, null);            
    } 
    finally 
    {
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

and with a WebView, this way:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google_graph);
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView12);
    String content = "MY HTML CODE HERE"
                    +"AND HERE"
                    +"AND SO ON";

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", content, "text/html", "utf-8", null );
    //webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Code.html"); // Can be used in this way too.
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Cognome_input:
        Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleGraph.this, GoogleImageGraphActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var dHOST                       = "ws://10.0.0.1:8080";

    var dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA         = 1;
    var dCONNESSIONE_INAPERTURA     = 2;
    var dCONNESSIONE_APERTA         = 3;
    var dCONNESSIONE_LOGININCORSO   = 4;
    var dCONNESSIONE_ATTIVA         = 5;

    var dAUTOMATICO = true;
    var dLOGINAUTO  = dAUTOMATICO;

    var connection = null;
    var connectionOpen = false;
    var ultimaStringa = null;
    var stato;

    // definisco prototipo per usare startsWith che è + chiara
    if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
        String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){

            return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
        };
    }

    aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA );

    function aggiornaInfoStato( stringa )
    {
        document.getElementById("stato").innerHTML = stringa;
    }
    function aggiornaStato( nuovostato )
    {

        if ( ! document.getElementById("stato") ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( nuovostato ) {
            stato = nuovostato;
        }

        if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA ) {
            aggiornaInfoStato( "non connesso" )
            document.getElementById("btnConnetti").value = " connetti ";
        }
        else if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_INAPERTURA ) {
            aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:navy'>connessione in corso ...</span>" );
            if ( document.getElementById("infopiano") ) {
                document.getElementById("infopiano").value = "";
            }
        }
        else if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_APERTA ) {
            aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:green'>CONNESSO ( login NON effettuato )</span>" );
            document.getElementById("btnConnetti").value = " disconnetti ";
        }
        else if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_LOGININCORSO ) {
            aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:navy'>login in corso ...</span>" );
        }
        else if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_ATTIVA ) {
            aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:green'>ATTIVA</span>" );
            if (document.getElementById("btnLogin")) document.getElementById("btnLogin").value = " riceProd ";
        }

        if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_APERTA )
            if (document.getElementById("btnLogin")) document.getElementById("btnLogin").value = " login ";
        else
            if (document.getElementById("btnLogin")) document.getElementById("btnLogin").value = " [disabled] ";

    }
    function connetti()
    {

        //alert( document.getElementById("userid").value );

        if ( !connection ) {

            aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_INAPERTURA );

            connection = new WebSocket( dHOST );

            connection.onopen = function () {
                console.log("connesso");
                aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_APERTA );
                if ( dLOGINAUTO || dAUTOMATICO ) {
                    login();
                }
            };

            connection.onclose = function (event) {
                console.log("connessione chiusa");
                if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA ) {
                    // mi arriva dopo ca. 10" (Chrome) o 15" (IE) che ho inviato connection.close()
                }
                else if ( stato <= dCONNESSIONE_INAPERTURA ) {
                    aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:red'>connessione fallita</span>" );
                }
                else {
                    aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:red'>connessione interrotta</span>" );
                }
                stato = dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA;
                connection=null;
            }

            connection.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('errore: ' + error);
                if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA ) {
                    // IE: mi arriva dopo 10"/15" che ho inviato connection.close()
                }
                else if ( stato >= dCONNESSIONE_ATTIVA ) {
                    aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:red'>connessione interrotta (err)</span>" );
                }
                else {
                    aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:red'>connessione fallita (err)</span>" );
                }
                connection=null;
                stato = dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA;
            };

            connection.onmessage = function (e) {
                var stringa = e.data;

                console.log('ricevuto: ' + stringa);

                // gestione dei msg ricevuti
                if ( stringa=='login: ok' ) {
                    aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_ATTIVA );
                    if ( dAUTOMATICO ) {
                        aggiornaInfoStato( "<span style='color:navy'>richiesta in corso ...</span>" );
                        login();
                    }
                }

                else if ( ultimaStringa.startsWith('riceprod: ') ) {

                    var aArray = JSON.parse(stringa);

                    alert( aArray.length );

                    alert( aArray[ 0 ] );

                    alert( aArray[ 0 ][ 0 ] );


                }


                else if ( stringa.startsWith('infopiano: ') ) {
                    var aArray = JSON.parse( stringa.substr(11) );
                    document.getElementById("infopiano").value = aArray[ 0 ];
                    aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_ATTIVA );
                    if ( dAUTOMATICO ) {
                        connetti();
                    }
                }

            };
        }
        else {

            aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_CHIUSA );
            connection.close();
            connection=null;

        }

    }
    function send( stringa )
    {
        if ( stato >= dCONNESSIONE_APERTA ) {
            connection.send( stringa );
            ultimaStringa=stringa;
        }
    }
    function login()
    {

        if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_APERTA ) {

            aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_LOGININCORSO );

            var userid  = document.getElementById("userid").value;
            var userpwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;

            send( "login: ['" + userid + "','" + userpwd + "','WebSocketApp']" );

        }
        else if ( stato == dCONNESSIONE_ATTIVA ) {

            aggiornaStato( dCONNESSIONE_ATTIVA );
        }

    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='100'>stato</td><td width='300'><span id='stato'>non connesso</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>user</td><td><input type='text' id='userid' value='demo_ws_userid'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pwd</td><td><input type='text' id='pwd' value='demo_ws_pwd'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><hr></td>
    </tr>
    <!--
    <tr>
        <td>id piano</td><td><input type='text' id='idpiano' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    -->
    <!--
    <tr>
        <td>residuo piano</td><td><input type='text' id='infopiano' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><hr></td>
    </tr>
    -->
    <tr>
        <td><input type='button' id='btnConnetti' value=' connetti ' onclick='connetti();'></td>
        <td><input type='button' id='btnLogin' value=' login ' onclick='riceProd();'></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It regularly work as a HTML page, but **it absolutely doesn't work in Android... please help me!**

Thanks a lot and have a nice programming :)

Here is the logcat with the message that i get when i press the "connetti" button from the webview in my android app:

```
08-27 08:39:31.236: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44

08-27 08:39:31.306: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0

08-27 08:39:31.576: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)

08-27 08:39:31.686: I/chromium(1244): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: connetti is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/ (1)

08-27 08:39:31.746: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44

08-27 08:39:31.816: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0

08-27 08:39:32.116: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)

08-27 08:39:32.216: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44

08-27 08:39:32.286: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0

08-27 08:39:32.556: E/eglCodecCommon(1244): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
```

Comment: please submit log cat output which error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular javascript was retired in recent WebView (more specifically Chromimum WebView).
You can achieve the desired effect in the following way:

1) First of all make sure the javascript is enabled. I suggest also browsing the available methods in webview settings, since you may find more usueful and required things there:

```
webview.getSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
```

2) Since 4.4 you do this by *evaluateJavascript()* which will asynchronously invoke the javascript and provide you with a callback:

```
String exampleScript = "(function() { return \"example\"; }) ();"

webView.evaluateJavascript(exampleScript, new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("LogName", s); // Prints 'this'
    }
});
```

3) Pre 4.4 you can use the JavaScriptInterface described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). Make note of the extra @JavascriptInterface annotation which is required for the intrface to work correctly on post SDK17 devices.